# WP Supersized: Insert zero in front of one digit slider numbers

Tags: plugins

I hope there is a WP Supersized champ out who know the answer to this one:
I would like to turn the one digit slide numbers in WP Superslider into two digit numbers. So 1/15 would be 01/15, 3/5 would be 03/05, and so on.
Can somebody help me, please? :)

Plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-supersized

**So far I have tried this script** - but it only works until it goes to next slide:

```
$(".number").text(function(i, val){
    return $.trim(val).length === 1 ? '0' + val : val;
});
```

**Also I think this PHP could work.** (But I can not figure out where to put it, because it is not clear to me where in the plugin the numbers are printed):

```
$number_padded = sprintf("%02s", $number);
echo $number_padded;
```

Comment: Plugin specific questions are mostly off topic. In any case, this one sounds like a php question

Comment: @PatJ Just updated my question with some of the code I have tried so far :-)